# When is Application.onCreate called by ContentProvider

Tags: android

I have an Android app which exposes the openFile method of ContentProvider.  The method access a variable initialized in the Application.onCreate method.  This data is being returned as null, however if I stick in a delay it will come back as initialized.  Any idea why null is returned unless I delay?  I thought this would all happen on the same thread.  See the code below.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private MyDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        database = new MyDatabase(this);
    }

    public MDRSDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }
}

public class ExternalContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // d will be null after the following call, but if I stick brief sleep here it won't be.
        MyDatabase d = (MyApplication)getContext().getApplicationContext().getDatabase();
    }
}
```

Update: Logging the thread ID in both the onCreate and openFile methods does indeed show that Application.onCreate is being called on a different thread than the ContentProvider.openFile.  What to do about this?  How does the ContentProvider know when onCreate has been completed?

Update 2: Following CommonsWare comment I have modified MyApplication.  This does seem to resolve the issue.  I have however been unable to find any decent documentation about this in my online searches so I'm flying blind to some extent here.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private MyDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        database = new MyDatabase(this);
    }

    public MDRSDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `ContentProvider` gets instantiated before `onCreate()` on the `Application` is called. That is why certain things, like ACRA, need to get initialized in `attachBaseContext()`, which is called before any `ContentProvider` is initialized. I am a bit surprised that `openFile()` would be called before `onCreate()` on `Application`, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks.  I was unaware of attachBaseContext and can hardly find a mention of it online, but it seems to do the trick.